# How to consume a jfrog artifactory in a maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, artifactory

I created a sample project A and pushed it to my jfrog artifactory. Now, I want to use this in another maven project B.

To achieve this, I added this dependency declaration (copied from jfrog) in B's pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.testartifactory.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>testartifactory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>testartifactory</id>
      <name>com.testartifactory.example</name>
      <url>https://myjfrogurl/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/testartifactory/example/testartifactory/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But when I import this `import com.testartifactory.example;`, I get error that `package com.testartifactory does not exist`.

Even though I can see the project downloaded in repositories under .m2 folder:
[image]

Here is how my project A is structured:

[image]

I am new to this so I may be doing something wrong and would appreciate any help.

Comment: In your import statement `import com.testartifactory.example;` aren't you missing either a class name or a star/asterisk (to import many classes) as in `import com.testartifactory.example.ClassName;` or `import com.testartifactory.example.*;`

Answer (score 0):

The repository URL should correspond to the repository in JFrog Artifactory. In your case: `https://myjfrogurl/artifactory/libs-release-local`

In the pom.xml:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>testartifactory</id>
      <name>com.testartifactory.example</name>
      <url>https://myjfrogurl/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Other options to use Artifactory for Maven builds are to use the [Artifactory Maven plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) or the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI). With these integrations, you'll get some more benefits such as build-info, Xray scanning, better performance and more.

Read more about Maven and Artifactory:

- [Maven Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository) in JFrog Artifactory
- [QuickStart Guide: Maven and Gradle](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/QuickStart+Guide%3A+Maven+and+Gradle)
- [Running Maven Builds](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningMavenBuilds) using the JFrog CLI